# Standard normal Probability. Values and reasoning

Tags: probability

1) $P(z > 1.8)= 1 - .8810= .119$

reasoning: Because we want the area beyond 1.8 we take 1 minus the area of $\Phi 1.8$

2) $P(1.5 \lt z \lt 1.8)= .9641-.9332=.0309$

reasoning: since we want the area between 1.5 and 1.8 we take the area of $\Phi 1.8-\Phi 1.5$

3) $P(-1.5 \lt Z lt 0)= 1-.0668=.9332$

reasoning: More easily it can just be stated because its between zero and 1.5, the area is the same value as 1.5(.9332). Or by the property of symmetry, $1 - -\Phi 1.5= 1-.0668$

4) $P(Z \lt -1.5)= .0668$

reasoning: We want the area beyond -1.5 so we have $1 - -\Phi 1.5= .0068$

5) $P(-1.8 \lt Z \lt -1.5)= .0309$

reasoning: This is the same as finding the area between $ \Phi 1.8 - \Phi 1.5=..9641-.9332$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have $\Phi(1.8) = 0.96407$, not $0.8810$; therefore **(1)** should be $\Pr[Z > 1.8] \approx 0.0359303$.  In fact, the answer to your second question uses the correct value for $\Phi(1.8)$.

**(2)** is correct.

**(3)** should be $\Pr[-1.5 \le Z \le 0] = 0.5 - 0.0668$ because $\Phi(0) = 1/2$.  The mean of a standard normal distribution is $0$, thus the probability that $Z$ is less than or equal to $0$ is $1/2$.

**(4)** is correct.

**(5)** is correct.  Note that this is equivalent to question **(2)**.